# Android animation TextView slow to up

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, textview

I need to do the same in the final of movies that show all informations about movie,

I need that a string going up followed that other, and in the end of the screen repeat the string again.

Some thing like this.

---

```
                             string1

                             string2

                             string3
```

---

---

```
                             string 2

                             string 3

                             string 1
```

---

---

```
                             string 3

                             string 1

                             string 2
```

---

But I need to change with slow movement.

Answer (score 3):

So you want animation that flows up? but for a movie you can use the text falling down
ok i got something for you here check this out , save it in your res/anim folder as falling .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
 </set>
```

and to use it just add this code in your java file

```
  final Animation falling= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.falling);
  textview.startAnimation();
```

modify the values to +ve in android :fromYDelta to get the flow.